# Dispatching threads/process for polling OIDs in python

Tags: python, multithreading, process, snmp, python-multithreading

I have a script that reads in a file that contains about 100 SNMP OIDs (1.3.6.x.x.x....) and I want to have them be polled against my router every 1, 5, or 30 mins depending.  I originally thought that I would create a new thread for each OID and have 100 threads polling the router at the same time, but ran into a problem with them taking up too much memory.  Using processes would take up more right?  Also, I saw python has event scheduling in the std lib is that something that would help? What about a thread pool?  What would be the quickest and most memory efficient way to poll 100 OIDs at a given interval?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you confirm if the OIDs to be polled are on a single device i.e. at one ip-address? From client (SNMP manager) perspective, how long does it take to retrieve (roundtrip) one of those OIDs? How long to walk them all in series (and is there a reason why you cant do it serially (fully or in part) ? Also are all the OIDs in the same branch of the OID tree, and if so can you so a SNMP-bulk walk ? How does your target device behave when it gets hit with many parallel SNMP GETs?

Comment: @k1eran The OIDs are all at different branches of the OID tree.  I am polling a single device (one ip address).  It takes about <500 ms roundtrip if I do a snmpget on a single  OID.   To get them all in series it takes longer than the interval time so I can't just snmpget one after another.  The target device returns them if I do it in parallel, but from the client side it can't handle that many threads at once.  Is this a hardware limitation or is there some better way other than threads to do it?

Comment: When the roundtrip is long like you describe, there is often a huge performance gain if you get several OIDs at once  (even if it means you pull back some OIDs that you don't care about!). Look at http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpbulkget.html and the "higher level" http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpbulkwalk.html. I think there is a chance that with BULK operations you may not need to delve into multi-threads/processes.

Comment: k1eran, that last comment would make the foundation of a decent answer for this question, I think!